# Adding an event in a dynamically generated class on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am attempting to loop a hover effect such that an image dances to the four corners of the site (top left corner -> top right corner -> bottom right corner -> bottom leftcorner -> then back up to the top left corner)

The way I am doing this is by adding a class, hoverleft, right, down, up, etc. and removing the previous class. The issue I have is that the dynamically added classes are not recognized after the page loads. I have been trying to work with the .on() function but have been having difficulty. Not sure why and pretty sure I am just missing something simple.

Here is what I have, HTML then JS: fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5w0nk6j9/4/

```
<div class="bodycontainer">
<div id="kim">
    <div id="dance" class="dancingkim">
    <div class="header">
        <h2 class="introheader">Hover original</h2>
    </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/240x208" />
</div>
</div>

$('#kim').hover(function(){
    $(".header h2").text("Hover text");
    });
    $('#kim').hover(function(){
    $(".dancingkim").css("cursor", "pointer");
});

$('.dancingkim').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hoverleft");
    $(this).removeClass("dancingkim");
});

$('#kim').on('hover', '.hoverleft', function() {
    $('#dance').addClass("hoverdown");
    $('#dance').removeClass("hoverleft");
});
```

Comment: so you want the image to  visit all the four corners on a single hover?

Comment: I want the image to hover left the first time it is hovered upon, then as a user moves their mouse to catch up to the image again it shoots downwards, and so on. So the user would be chasing the picture for the entire visit to the site

Comment: i was able to accomplish with a random margin added to the image on every hover without class changes but id prefer to do it with a slide effect.

Answer (score 0):

In place of hover, try using **mouseover** or **mouseenter** or **mouseleave**.

```
$('#kim').on('mouseover', '.hoverleft', function() {
    $('#dance').addClass("hoverdown");
    $('#dance').removeClass("hoverleft");
});
```

From the JQuery source code, hover is not included in the event list that triggered leading to JQuery .on()

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically generated elements are referenced by using `.on()` but it should be implemented on the document body. The javascript traverses the whole document and adds the property to it. 
So, instead of using :

```
$('#kim').on('hover', '.hoverleft', function() {
$('#dance').addClass("hoverdown");
$('#dance').removeClass("hoverleft");
});
```

Try this:

```
$('body').on('mouseover', "#kim", function(){
$(this).next().addClass("hoverdown");
$(this).next().removeClass("hoverleft");
});
```